# way to provide a path to controller file using ui-router

Tags: angularjs

is there any way to provide a path to a controller file by using UI-ROUTER

this is my code

```
var kraveln = angular.module('kraveln', ['ui.router' , 'ngMessages' , 'ngDialog'  ]);

kraveln.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
// for home_page
         .state('home', {
            url: '/home',// if home page means
            views: {
                '': 
                { 
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/home_search_page.html',
                    controller: 'app/views/sample_controller.js' // sample controller for  loading file.  
                 },
                'header_part': 
                { 
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/header_one.html'  //load first header
                },
                 'footer_part': 
                { 
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/footer.html'  //load second footer
                }
            }
        })
```

as like the template url can we load controller URL i tried but can't able to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes you can give a specific controller to every view in a state.**

```
.state('home',{
          url: '/home',
          views: {
            '': {
              templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
              controller: 'MainController',
              controllerAs: 'main'
            },
            'header': {
              templateUrl: 'app/main/header.html',
              controller: 'HeaderController',
              controllerAs: 'header'
            },
            'footer': {
              templateUrl: 'app/main/footer.html'
            }
          }
   })
```

[reference link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/multiple-named-views)

Comment: yes .. and the error is 

[ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=app%2Fcomponents%2Fcontrollers%2Fcuisines_controller.js&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: is there any way to implement URL to the controller as like the template URL .. i mean as like ` templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',` can we give to controller too ? now i"m giving in main js file where modules and all available

Comment: no need to give the controller path, if you load the controller in the mail htm file, the controller name is sucfficient.

Comment: for example if i want to use a controller in my file means i have to define those things as `<script src="app/views/sample_controller.js" />` in my index file right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126210/discussion-between-ramanaa-gj-and-sravan).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Angularjs pick the HTML templates from the directory using relative address mechanism.

For controllers, you need to register/include all the JS file in your index.html.

```
<script src="app/views/sample_controller.js" />
//....Same for others...
```

And include it in router or states like this.

```
controller: 'SampleController',
```

Hope, Your query resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do lazy load with `oclazyload` module.

Check samples at, https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/with-your-router

```
$stateProvider.state('index', {
  url: "/", // root route
  views: {
    "lazyLoadView": {
      controller: 'AppCtrl', // This view will use AppCtrl loaded below in the resolve
      templateUrl: 'partials/main.html'
    }
  },
  resolve: { // Any property in resolve should return a promise and is executed before the view is loaded
    loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
      // you can lazy load files for an existing module
             return $ocLazyLoad.load('js/AppCtrl.js');
    }]
  }
});
```